# DNS lookup python socket.getHostbyName vs nslookup

Tags: python, dns, nslookup

I am having trouble resolving dns lookups in my script. But using the nslookup command in a shell resolves fine for the same entry. Does anyone have an idea why it would behave like that ?

The error I am getting is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/replay_engine_app/replay_engine/replay_engine.py", line 42, in connectDevice
    client_handle = socket.gethostbyname(dns_address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

dns_address printed from code :

> device-simulator-0.device.default.svc.cluster.local

Screenshot of the nslookup command:

[image: Screenshot of the nslookup command]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Could you perhaps supply us with the **relevant** code? For instance, what is `dns_address`?

Comment: The code willmight be more confusing actually. let's say dns_adress is device-simulator-0.device.default.svc.cluster.local it gives me an error in python but using nslookup with the same adress gives me the result @Torxed

Comment: I would like to see a nslookup screenshot or output and I'd like to see what `dns_address` actually is. Where you define it and to what (copy paste, no manual rewriting because I'm almost certain this is a spelling error).

Comment: @Torxed I updated my question. please take a look at it

Comment: You're running the nslookup in a container (kubernetes). Where are you running your Python code?

Comment: Inside that same container @Torxed

Comment: Weird. Could you try the following: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/5ef2b9c46794aeaa90d205a9d2414311

Comment: Also check `client_handle` in your code, because it might not be empty. It might just be that there's no local resolv in `/etc/hosts` and there for `gethostbyname` will raise an exception (strange behavior).

Comment: @Torxed so you mean it could just be an irrelevant error ?

Comment: Sort of, yes. Most likely it will be hard to distinguish this name resolv issue from a real one, so swapping libraries to get better control over this flow might be in your favor.

Comment: Well i guess it's not library: https://gist.github.com/traoremp/e3f24a8180e4e396adb9e37ed77442cf

Comment: This is extremely strange. Same result with just my code? Without threading and other weird things. Does the code work locally on your computer?

Comment: Yes but not in container @Torxed

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/48#issuecomment-330244061 is this your exact issue and solution?

Comment: @Torxed so at last, I found the solution. The behaviour was due to Kubernetes. the DNS servers seem to become ready after the pod is running. so I was making queries before the  DNS was ready.

Comment: Sweet! Yea that seems logical, I assumed the service startup procedure was done so that the scripts service had networking as a dependency :) Write up a answer for your problem so others easily find the solution, and mark your own answer as a accepted solution! :)